# Why CSS target tag is not working on html id

Tags: css

everyone.
I'm studying html/css basic.
but I met some problem for css target tag

When I tried 'target' to some 'id(intro)', it is not work.
ex)

```
<style>
    #intro:target{
        border: 5px #000 solid;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>

<ul id="intro">
    <li><a href="#lit">menu test</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="lit"> affected</p>
```

However, when I tried this without 'id(intro)' like below, it worked well.

```
 <style>
    :target{
        border: 5px #000 solid;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Learn more about [:target](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use selector target #lit, intro is not target, target will read url.
not the other way around

```html
<style>
    #lit:target{
        border: 5px #000 solid;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>

<ul id="intro">
    <li><a href="#lit">menu test</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="lit"> affected</p>
```

Comment: Thanks to @Yudono. 
I misnuderstand target will work to intro's child selector.